# Python add commas to integers recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a function that will add commas to an integer n and return the result as a string.

For example, numbers less than 1000 have no commas added; the number 1343456765 would be returned as '1,343,456,765'.

```
def commas(n):

    if len(n)<4:
        return 'n'
    else:
        return (recursive formula)
```

Comment: Is using recursion such a bad thing? I find it perfectly acceptable to learn different ways of writing the same function. It's best to be knowledge of many different ways of thinking!

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring your recursive request, here's an easy way to add commas:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
'en_US'
>>> locale.format('%d', 1343456765, grouping=True)
'1,343,456,765'
>>> locale.format('%d', 1000, grouping=True)
'1,000'
>>> locale.format('%d', 999, grouping=True)
'999'
```

Comment: Or, in Python 2.7+, if you only require the `,` as a thousands sep, it's simpler to use `format(number, ',')`

Answer (score 1):

Think, if you have 12345 and you know the the format for 12, then how will you compute for 12345 ?

```
def comma(n):
    if not isinstance(n,str): n = str(n)
    if len(n) < 4: return n
    else: return comma(n[:-3]) + ',' + n[-3:]
```

Comment: I tried this and it says there is an error and I can't find the length of an integer- which makes sense but then do I need to convert the integer to a string to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using duck typing since the normal case would be a `str` input after the first recursion:

```
def commas(s):
    try:
        return s if len(s)<4 else commas(s[:-3]) + ',' + s[-3:] 
    except TypeError:
        return commas(str(s))

>>> commas(10**20)
'100,000,000,000,000,000,000'
```

But it would be better to just require a string input:

```
def commas(s):
        return s if len(s)<4 else commas(s[:-3]) + ',' + s[-3:]

>>> commas(str(10**20))
'100,000,000,000,000,000,000'
```